# ASP.NET Core 7 - gRPC + Negotiate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a gRPC server on ASP.NET Core 7 and would like to ensure that only users of a particular on-prem AD group are able to access it.

I've added the following configuration to `program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ADGroupPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.RequireRole("<group1>", "<group2>");
    });
});
// ...
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.MapGet("/",() => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");
    
app.Run();
```

But I can still access it from a user not in the groups and the server log shows:

```
Negotiate is not supported with HTTP/2.
AuthenticationScheme: Negotiate was not authenticated
```

How can I get my gRPC server to only allow users that are a member of a particular group/groups?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with a level of indirection. You want to make an endpoint that requires the negotiate auth scheme and exchange that for an auth token (embedded whatever information is required to look up that user). Then you can protect your grpc server endpoints with that token. (using whatever claims are embedded or by extract the claims and doing a deeper query against AD to find the user information and groups).

Comment: Could you provide some code or links explaining *how* to actually do that?

Comment: Yes, the difficulty is in the token issuing, there's nothing build into ASP.NET Core to do this until .NET 8. That means you'll need to issue the token yourself. There's also one more difficulty in that you need to get the token on an HTTP/1.x connection since negotiate doesn't work on H2.